# How to set up Nginx config to rewrite my subdomain

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, subdomain

I'm try to set up the subdomains with Nginx, but I get some error. The following is my config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dimain.com *.domain.com;
    root /path/to/fuelphp_project/public;

    location / {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        if ($host ~ (.*)\.(.*) ) {
                set $sub_name $1;
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$sub_name/$1 last;
                break;
        }

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
            break;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

I want to the results like:

```
sub1.domain.com/c1/a1 -> domain.com/sub1/c1/a1
sub2.domain.com/c2/a2 -> domain.com/sub2/c2/a2
```

How to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
  server_name sub1.domain.com;
  return 301 "http://domain.com/sub1${uri}";
}
```

Would this work for you?

I just noticed an answer to this here: https://serverfault.com/questions/426673/nginx-redirect-subdomain-to-sub-directory

```
server {
  server_name ~^(?<sub>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com$; # will cause the sub-domain to be placed in $sub
  return 301 "http://domain.com/${sub}${uri}";
}
```

I think the regular expression also can be a very cool solution... Depends what you need.

Comment: You need to restart the nginx after changes to the .conf.